# Firebase crashlytics not able to read crash reports

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics, crash-reports

I have configured **crashlytics** as per Firebase Documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android.
But crash reports not generated and uploaded to server.

[image: server]

Kindly refer my build details.

Here is our project-level **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'}
        maven{ url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
        mavenCentral()

        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXX.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 375
        versionName "2.25.1"

        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }

    android {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "appVariant", "projectCode"
    productFlavors {
        A {
            applicationId 'com.XXX.A'
            dimension "appVariant"
        }
        B {
            applicationId 'com.XXX.B'
            dimension "appVariant"
        }
        C {
            applicationId 'com.XXX.C'
            dimension "appVariant"
        }
        D {
            applicationId 'com.XXX.D'
            dimension "appVariant"
        }
        DEV {
            dimension "projectCode"
        }
        QA {
            dimension "projectCode"
        }
        LIVE {
            dimension "projectCode"
        }
        DEMO {
            dimension "projectCode"
        }
        BETA {
            dimension "projectCode"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            def project = "XXX"
            def SEP = "_"
            def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name
            def projcode = variant.productFlavors[1].name
            def buildType = variant.buildType.name
            def buildTypeName = "";
            switch (buildType) {
                case "ABC": buildTypeName = SEP + "AB"; break;
                case "XYZ": buildTypeName = SEP + "XY"; break;
                default:
                    buildTypeName = "";
            }

            def version = variant.versionName
            def newApkName = project + buildTypeName + SEP + flavor + SEP + projcode + SEP + version + ".apk"

            outputFileName = new File(newApkName)
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            buildConfigField "String", "AREA", "\"\""
        }
        
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            buildConfigField "String", "AREA", "\"\""
        }
        ABC {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            minifyEnabled false
            buildConfigField "String", "AREA", "\"_A\""
        }
        XYZ {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            buildConfigField "String", "AREA", "\"_X\""
        }
    }
    
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

repositories {

    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }

}

dependencies {
    def room_version = "1.1.1"
    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
    def work_version = "1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation files('libs/commons-net-3.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.3.4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.3.4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/silipmlib.jar')
    implementation files('libs/HyperLogLib8.jar')
    
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.0')
    
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'

    //dependency for Workmanager
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.0.1'

    //dependencies for Room database
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    //dependency for custom progress dialog

    //dependency for retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

    //dependency for joda time for date time calculation
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10'

    //dependency for glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    //dependency for custom toast
    implementation 'com.valdesekamdem.library:md-toast:0.9.0'

    //dependency for marshmallow permission - dexter library
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0'

    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of compiler
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation project(':floatingmenu')
    implementation project(':html2bitmap')
    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.vipulasri:timelineview:1.0.6'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.haozhang.libary:android-slanted-textview:1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

    // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'

    // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    implementation 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'

    //  implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.8.4'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:2.3.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-legacy:2.3.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-integration:2.3.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    implementation files('libs/HyperLogLib8.jar')
    implementation project(':scandecode-release')
    implementation 'com.tt:whorlviewlibrary:1.0.3'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-design:0.4.0'

    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.7'

    // these are for retrolambda and streams api
    implementation 'com.annimon:stream:1.1.2'

}
```

**With initialisation:**

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```

**And manifest:**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="true" />
```

Here is the logcat for the Crashlytics/CrashTest crash:

```
2022-04-10 15:53:07.717 21310-21310/com.XXX.XXX E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.XXX.XXX, PID: 21310
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Crash
        at com.XXX.XXX.UI.HomeActivity$1.onClick(HomeActivity.java:345)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6392)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25133)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7055)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:523)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:836)
```

This is the log that we receive when app relaunched after crash.

```
D:\user\Android Projects\XXX>adb logcat -s FirebaseCrashlytics
--------- beginning of main
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of crash
04-10 15:54:56.911 22018 22018 I FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Firebase Crashlytics 18.2.9 for com.XXX.XXX
04-10 15:54:56.926 22018 22018 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
04-10 15:54:56.940 22018 22018 D FirebaseCrashlytics: AnalyticsConnector now available.
04-10 15:54:56.943 22018 22018 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Registered Firebase Analytics listener.
04-10 15:54:56.948 22018 22018 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Mapping file ID is: 00000000000000000000000000000000
04-10 15:54:56.958 22018 22018 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Checking for cached settings...
04-10 15:54:56.992 22018 22018 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Loaded cached settings: {"settings_version":3,"cache_duration":86400,"features":{"collect_logged_exceptions":true,"collect_reports":
true,"collect_analytics":false,"prompt_enabled":false,"push_enabled":false,"firebase_crashlytics_enabled":false,"collect_anrs":true,"collect_metric_kit":false},"app":{"status":"activated
","update_required":false,"report_upload_variant":2,"native_report_upload_variant":2},"fabric":{"org_id":"62513aa60277ea5e0396d4ef","bundle_id":"com.XXX.XXX"},"on_demand_
upload_rate_per_minute":10,"on_demand_backoff_base":1.2,"on_demand_backoff_step_duration_seconds":60,"expires_at":1649666891559}
04-10 15:54:56.996 22018 22018 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
04-10 15:54:57.113 22018 22018 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Successfully configured exception handler.
04-10 15:54:57.116 22018 22049 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Opening a new session with ID 6252B07803E20001560228F94565CB5E
04-10 15:54:57.183 22018 22049 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Registered Firebase Analytics event receiver for breadcrumbs
04-10 15:54:58.013 22018 22018 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
04-10 15:54:58.642 22018 22018 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
```

These are set to false in cached settings:

```
"collect_analytics":false,
"firebase_crashlytics_enabled":false,
```

This setting was weird. Both of them are false for some reason though I never did turn them off explicitly. Never even played with these settings.

**Not sure what is wrong**.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried test crashing and checked for the result

Comment: @Sayooj Yes, I have posted the logs at app relaunch. But no logs received from FirebaseCrashlytics after crash.

Comment: Oops. Let me see again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solved!..***
There was another utility logger library initialized in the application class that prevented crashlytics from collecting log. https://github.com/hypertrack/hyperlog-android .  This library prevented the app from crashing. As we know crashlytics crash report collection works only if the app crashes. As I threw the uncaught exception... the app froze, and it didn't crash. After I commented the code that initializes this library from the application class. It started working like a charm.

See the reply that I got from GitHub.
[image]
The first one seems to be my issue.

Also the initialization & manifest part is not necessary unless you want to explicitly enable/disable crashlytics working.